# Converting UTC to PDT in excel

Tags: excel, timestamp

How can I convert a UTC timestamp like these to a PDT timestamp in excel? I tried subtracting 7/24 but I only get ########

```
13 19:09:27
27 17:50:50
05 20:56:41
```

Comment: expand the column the `##` means the column is too small to show the result.

Comment: Show the formula you actually used.

Comment: I assume the number before the time is the day of the month.  Without more info Excel will assume that day is in January 1900.  Just an FYI.

Comment: 1. Text to columns to separate the day of the month and formatted the time as hh:mm:ss 2. Tried subtracting 7/24 from the resulting cell value 3.

Comment: Then the `###` are because your time is going negative when the time is less than `07:00:00` time cannot be negative.

Comment: You are right, I guess. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: you need to start with the whole string and make that an actual date/time and then subtract.  They you can parse out just the time if you want.  If you show how the string comes in we can help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Scott. I formatted the below values as Long Date. The resulting strings were the same. I then tried subtracting 7/24 and it showed me #value

01 02:52:12

13 15:58:57

17 19:02:37

12 04:01:57

08 23:46:38

Comment: There is no month or year data with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just have d hh:mm:ss in UTC that needs to be converted to PST. In fact, I have multiple such columns. Later on, I will have subtract the timestamps to get the hours/min difference between these two timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the orignal data and use this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,2)+RIGHT(A1,8)-7/24
```

Then format as desired.

[image]

Comment: Woot! This works very well, Scott. Thank you so much